# Sobrepor valor de estilos passados dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando o **jquery superfish** para fazer algumas otimizações em um menu. Esse plugin passa o valor `display:none` ou block para o elemento `sub-menu`

Desse jeito:

`<ul class="sub-menu" style="display:none">
</ul>`

O que eu gostaria de fazer agora é, sobrepor com javascript o valor desse display em um nível especifico desse menu. Especificamente no nível 3.

`.nav ul li ul.sub-menu li .ul.sub-menu2 li ul.sub-menu3{}`

Assim:

`<ul class="sub-menu" style="display:none">
 <ul class="sub-menu2" style="display:none">
   <ul class="sub-menu3" style="display:none">
  </ul>
 </ul>
</ul>`

Quero substituir o `none` por inline-block no **sub-menu3**

DEMO: https://superfish.joelbirch.co/examples/

Comment: @dvd como deveríamos fazer? Veja, isso aqui funcionou do modo como eu esperava. Gostaria de fazer o mesmo, mas com DOM, e se fosse possível não alterar, mas simplesmente remover o valor logo. `$('.priority-nav ul li.full-menu-col ul.sub-menu li.has-children > ul.sub-menu').css('display', 'inline-block')`

Comment: @dvd, eu estou ciente que eu poderia resolver isso com um simples `!important` no meu arquivo .css mas...

Comment: @dvd Eu utilizei essa class sub-menu3 para exemplificar onde eu gostaria de remover.

Comment: Não para utilizar através da hierarquia igual no jquery? eu notei que com jquery tem um atraso, e também o display none volta quando hover.

Comment: Não utilizo div, apenas ul.

Comment: Pode selecionar o 3º ul assim: `document.querySelector('ul ul ul');`